# How to show activity indicator at the start of the app in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

I have app in which if there is data in local data base then it will first upload it to server before starting the application i have written the upload code in app Deleage I want that while uploading is going on how to show activiy indicator with alert.
Normally it is easy to show to startAnimating and Stop, but how to do in this scenario?

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    


     [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];


     NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     self.coffeeArray = tempArray;
     [tempArray release];

     [Coffee checkData:[self getDBPath]];


  int mytestcount=rowCount;
        NSLog(@"My Test ROw Count IS %d",mytestcount);


    if (mytestcount=0) {


    NSLog("No Data To Upload");

    }


   else {


    [Coffee getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];

    [self uploadData];
   }


   [self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];

       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

       return YES;
      }
```

Comment: How this is different from 'normally'?

Comment: (Even better, how on Earth is this related to Xcode? Have you read its tag wiki?)

Comment: @This site is not for crticizing any body but to help if i have given any wrong tag then its ok i will remove it

Comment: the point is not the criticism - the point is that one should learn to properly use the site. As I said, the Xcode tag is not for general iOS-related questions, it's about the IDE itself. Hell, I've been developing iOS apps for 2 years and yet never used Xcode.

Comment: add activity indicator on window  and start animating in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @H2CO3 and Nazia cool down ... Solve the issue rather than teaching ethics....

Comment: @Pricne i have written above code can you add your line where to add the activity animating

Comment: @NaziaJan try and put it in ViewDidLoad and as soon as the app starts the activity indicator will startanimating ...

Comment: but my upload code is loading before viewDidLoad in appDelegate

Comment: @NaziaJan : I think what H2CO3 wants to say here is, once the question is tagged, it is referred by fellow stack overflow users in future. Improper tagging may mislead users what they actually are searching for. Its really great that you rectified.

Comment: @Nitish yes i have removed tag

Comment: @TejeshwarGill can you explain more please

Comment: @NaziaJan c whenever ur app loads or the view loads the first method called is the ViewDidLoad rite? So if you put your ActivityIndicator code in there then it would start Animating as soon as your view loads ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Displaying `UIActivityIndicator` for this operation requires putting it in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** of **appDelegate**. Perform uploading in different thread so that indicator is displayed as long as operation is carried out. The change will be as follows :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

        [self copyDatabaseIfNeeded];
        NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.coffeeArray = tempArray;
        [tempArray release];
        [Coffee checkData:[self getDBPath]];
        int mytestcount=rowCount;
        NSLog(@"My Test ROw Count IS %d",mytestcount);
        if (mytestcount=0) {
            NSLog("No Data To Upload");
        }
       else {
            [Coffee getInitialDataToDisplay:[self getDBPath]];
            //Set activity indicator here and perform uploading in different thread so that indicator is displayed as long as operation is carried out.  

           [self performSelector:@selector(uploadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
       }
       [self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
       [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
       return YES;
      }
```

Creating a `UIActivityIndicator` in an alert is not difficult task. You can do it as follows :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" " message:@" " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *progress= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125, 50, 30, 30)];
progress.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
[alert addSubview:progress];
[progress startAnimating];   
[alert show];
```

You can customize your **alert** as you like it to be.
Hope this helps.

Comment: i am puting after  where you have writteh that put your alert code here